# LoadViewState not fired on my user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, viewstate, loadviewstate

I have a user control nested in a repeater.
Inside my user control I have another repeater and in that I have a panel.

I am trying to override the LoadViewState event of my user control and dynamically add controls to the panel.  I want to do it in the LoadViewState so that the dynamic controls get added before the viewstate gets loaded, so they retain their values after post backs.

For some reason the LoadViewState event on the user control (ascx) is not firing.  Is there some way to force it to fire, or is there another method I could use?  I have ruled out the user controls repeater databind event, because I need it to work even if data binding isn't happening and I can't do it on the repeaters item created event either because the child panel and inner html doesn't exist yet.

Comment: can you post your code-behind? or a sample of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LoadViewState` isn't the appropriate place for adding child controls.  For dynamically adding controls within a user control, you'll want to look at the [CreateChildControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx) method.

It's not firing a `LoadViewState` event because you need to save at least one value in the `ViewState` to have the event fire.

Comment: how about WebCotnrols? LoadViewState not fired in my WebControl. I have created a class that inherits from WebControl.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem with some dynamically created children user controls. `LoadViewState` wasn't called in postbacks even if I was able to access their ViewState when creating them first. `SaveViewState` seemed to be also called correctly. It ended that the children ViewState was not really usable (without this resulting in an exception) in the page `Init` event before they were fully initializated, and this happened only when the controls were added to the parent. After having ensured this, the children ViewState was correctly persisted across postbacks.

```
    // Belongs to a Page. If you create the children control in the
    // Load event in you can also access the page ViewState
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            for (int it = 0; it < 5; it++)
            {
                ChildControl child = LoadControl("ChildControl.ascx")
                    as ChildControl;
                child.ParentPage = this;
                TabPanel tab = tabContainer.FindControl("TabPanel" + it)
                    as TabPanel;
                // Ensure to add the child control to its parent before
                // accessing its ViewState!
                tab.Controls.Add(child);     // <---
                string caption = "Ciao" + it;
                child.Caption = caption;     // Here we access the ViewState
                tab.HeaderText = caption;
                tab.Visible = true;
                _Children.Add(child);
            }
        }
        [...]
    }

    // Belongs to ChildControl 
    public string Caption
    {
        get { return ViewState["Caption"] as string; }
        internal set { this.ViewState["Caption"] = value; }
    }
```